# Is $\frac{x^2 + 2x}{x}$ a polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Is $$\dfrac{x^2 + 2x}{x}$$ a polynomial?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: One argument against it being a polynomial would be that the domain doesn't include zero, and a polynomial has always domain = $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: And so $ \frac{9}{3}$ is not an integer ?

Comment: @SeñorBilly A polynomial does not "always" have domain $\mathbb{R}$. Remember, domains are specified, not intrinsic.

Comment: There are some good reasons not to define a polynomial as a function.

Comment: So it seems the answer depends on your definition of polynomial.

Comment: @TonyK Definitely. If the expression is considered as an element of $\mathbb{R}(x)$ (the field of fractions of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$), then it is certainly a polynomial, because we can “cancel out the $x$”. As a function of a real variable, it is not a polynomial function, because its domain is not $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @user1952009 You're comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: It's definitely a polynomial almost everywhere :P

Comment: @egreg $\frac{9}{3} =3$ is really the same as $\frac{x^{2}}{x} = x$

Comment: @user1952009 Depending on *where* you're working; in the framework of real functions of a real variable, they're not the same.

Comment: @user1952009 Not really: 9/3 = 3 is _always true_; $x^2/x=x$ is only correct if $x \ne 0$; since the left-hand side is undefined for $x=0$.

Answer (score 4):

Some people would say that the rational number $7/1$ is not really **equal** to the integer $7$, but merely **canonically identified** with it.  But (after reaching a certain level of sophistication) mathematicians say that $7/1$ and $7$ are indeed equal.

---

Some people would say that the rational function
$$
\frac{x^2+2x}{x}
\tag{*}$$
is not really **equal** to the polynomial
$$
x+2, 
\tag{**}$$
but merely **canonically identified** with it.  But (after reaching a certain level of sophistication) mathematicians say that (*) and (**) are indeed equal.

Comment: It may depend on the context, but there is some subtlety to this analogy (as pointed out in the comments). If you, after canonical identification, indeed would say they are *equal*, then what about (what happens at) $x=0$...?

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's a polynomial in the variable $t=\tfrac{x^2+2x}{x}$... But you probably mean a polynomial in the (real?) variable $x$. What precise **definition** of polynomial are you using?

---

I would say no, because it is not of the form
$$a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\ldots+a_nx^n$$
for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and real numbers $a_i$ ($0 \le i \le n$).

Note that you cannot just simplify
$$\frac{x^2+2x}{x} = x+2$$
as this equality is only valid for non-zero $x$, so not for all $x$.